# Equalizer, BiQuad filter crackling

Tags: java, android, audio, decoder, equalizer

I am programming an media player android app.

I want using the `AudioTrack` class because I want using an equalizer that have more than 5 Bands.

My problem is, I decode the .mp3 file and play the sample with `AudioTrack`. This works great, but when i am using the BiQuad peakEq filter, my track crackling at the frequencys where I want boost.

Here is my Code:

```
Player.java:

 public class Player {

        private static final String TAG = Player.class.getSimpleName();

        public short[] buffer;
        public boolean firstStart = false;
        public static volatile int position = 0;

        public static short[] decode(String path, int startMs, int maxMs)
                throws IOException, DecoderException {
            short[] pcm = new short[16070400];
            int position = 0;
            float totalMs = 0;
            boolean seeking = true;
            File file = new File(path);
            InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(
                    file), (8 * 1024));
            try {
                Bitstream bitstream = new Bitstream(inputStream);
                Decoder decoder = new Decoder();
                boolean done = false;
                while (!done) {
                    Header frameHeader = bitstream.readFrame();
                    if (frameHeader == null) {
                        done = true;
                    } else {
                        totalMs += frameHeader.ms_per_frame();
                        if (totalMs >= startMs) {
                            seeking = false;
                        }
                        if (!seeking) {
                            SampleBuffer output = (SampleBuffer) decoder
                                    .decodeFrame(frameHeader, bitstream);
                            if (output.getSampleFrequency() != 44100
                                    || output.getChannelCount() != 2) {
                                throw new DecoderException(
                                        "mono or non-44100 MP3 not supported", null);
                            }
                            short[] buffer = output.getBuffer();
                            for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
                                pcm[position] = buffer[i];
                                position++;
                            }
                        }
                        if (totalMs >= (startMs + maxMs)) {
                            done = true;
                        }
                    }
                    bitstream.closeFrame();
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "position " + position);
                return pcm;
            } catch (BitstreamException e) {
                throw new IOException("Bitstream error: " + e);
            } catch (DecoderException e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Decoder error", e);
                throw new DecoderException(maxMs, e);
            } finally {
            }
        }

        private void fillBuffer(short[] samples) {

            BiQuad filter = new BiQuad(FilterType.PEAK, (63.0 / 44100.0), 0.707, 5.0);

            for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
                buffer[i] = (short) filter.process(buffer[i]);
            }
        }

        public void playWithAudioTrack() throws IllegalArgumentException,
                SecurityException, IllegalStateException, IOException,
                DecoderException {

            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    try {
                        String path = "/storage/sdcard0/Music/lordi.mp3";
                        MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                        mPlayer.setDataSource(path);
                        mPlayer.prepare();
                        int durationMs = mPlayer.getDuration();

                        if (!firstStart) {
                            buffer = decode(path, 0, durationMs);
                        }

                        fillBuffer(buffer);

                        int minSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(44100,
                                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO,
                                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
                        AudioTrack track = new AudioTrack(
                                AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44100,
                                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO,
                                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, minSize,
                                AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

                        track.play();

                        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
                            track.write(buffer, i, buffer.length);
                        }

                        track.release();
                        firstStart = true;

                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (SecurityException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    catch (DecoderException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {

                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }
```

And here the BuQuad.java:

```
public class BiQuad
{   


 FilterType filterType;

    double a0, a1, a2, b1, b2;  

    double Fc, Q, peakGain;

    double z1, z2;



    public enum FilterType
    {
        LOWPASS,
        HIGHPASS,
        BANDPASS,
        NOTCH,
        PEAK,
        LOWSHELF,
        HIGHSHELF;
    };

    public float process(float in)
    {
        double out = in * a0 + z1;
        z1 = in * a1 + z2 - b1 * out;
        z2 = in * a2 - b2 * out;
        return (float)out;
    }


    public BiQuad()
    {
        filterType = FilterType.LOWPASS;
        a0 = 1.0f;
        a1 = a2 = b1 = b2 = 0.0f;
        Fc = 0.50f;
        Q = 0.707f;
        peakGain = 0.0f;
        z1 = z2 = 0.0f;
    }

    public BiQuad(FilterType filterType, double Fc, double Q, double peakGainDB)
    {
         setBiquad(filterType, Fc, Q, peakGainDB);
         z1 = z2 = 0.0f;
    }


    public void setType(FilterType filterType) {
        this.filterType = filterType;
        calcBiquad();
    }

    public void setQ(double Q) {
        this.Q = Q;
        calcBiquad();
    }

    public void setFc(double Fc) {
        this.Fc = Fc;
        calcBiquad();
    }

    public void setPeakGain(double peakGainDB) {
        this.peakGain = peakGainDB;
        calcBiquad();
    }

    public void setBiquad(FilterType filterType, double Fc, double Q, double peakGainDB) {
        this.filterType = filterType;
        this.Q = Q;
        this.Fc = Fc;
        setPeakGain(peakGainDB);
    }

    public void calcBiquad() {
        double norm;
        double V = Math.pow(10, Math.abs(peakGain) / 20.0);
        double K = Math.tan(Math.PI * Fc);
        switch (this.filterType) {
            case LOWPASS:
                norm = 1 / (1 + K / Q + K * K);
                a0 = K * K * norm;
                a1 = 2 * a0;
                a2 = a0;
                b1 = 2 * (K * K - 1) * norm;
                b2 = (1 - K / Q + K * K) * norm;
                break;

            case HIGHPASS:
                norm = 1 / (1 + K / Q + K * K);
                a0 = 1 * norm;
                a1 = -2 * a0;
                a2 = a0;
                b1 = 2 * (K * K - 1) * norm;
                b2 = (1 - K / Q + K * K) * norm;
                break;

            case BANDPASS:
                norm = 1 / (1 + K / Q + K * K);
                a0 = K / Q * norm;
                a1 = 0;
                a2 = -a0;
                b1 = 2 * (K * K - 1) * norm;
                b2 = (1 - K / Q + K * K) * norm;
                break;

            case NOTCH:
                norm = 1 / (1 + K / Q + K * K);
                a0 = (1 + K * K) * norm;
                a1 = 2 * (K * K - 1) * norm;
                a2 = a0;
                b1 = a1;
                b2 = (1 - K / Q + K * K) * norm;
                break;

            case PEAK:
                if (peakGain >= 0) {    // boost
                    norm = 1 / (1 + 1/Q * K + K * K);
                    a0 = (1 + V/Q * K + K * K) * norm;
                    a1 = 2 * (K * K - 1) * norm;
                    a2 = (1 - V/Q * K + K * K) * norm;
                    b1 = a1;
                    b2 = (1 - 1/Q * K + K * K) * norm;
                }
                else {    // cut
                    norm = 1 / (1 + V/Q * K + K * K);
                    a0 = (1 + 1/Q * K + K * K) * norm;
                    a1 = 2 * (K * K - 1) * norm;
                    a2 = (1 - 1/Q * K + K * K) * norm;
                    b1 = a1;
                    b2 = (1 - V/Q * K + K * K) * norm;
                }
                break;
            case LOWSHELF:
                if (peakGain >= 0) {    // boost
                    norm = 1 / (1 + Math.sqrt(2.0) * K + K * K);
                    a0 = (1 + Math.sqrt(2.0*V) * K + V * K * K) * norm;
                    a1 = 2 * (V * K * K - 1) * norm;
                    a2 = (1 - Math.sqrt(2.0*V) * K + V * K * K) * norm;
                    b1 = 2 * (K * K - 1) * norm;
                    b2 = (1 - Math.sqrt(2.0) * K + K * K) * norm;
                }
                else {    // cut
                    norm = 1 / (1 + Math.sqrt(2.0*V) * K + V * K * K);
                    a0 = (1 + Math.sqrt(2.0) * K + K * K) * norm;
                    a1 = 2 * (K * K - 1) * norm;
                    a2 = (1 - Math.sqrt(2.0) * K + K * K) * norm;
                    b1 = 2 * (V * K * K - 1) * norm;
                    b2 = (1 - Math.sqrt(2.0*V) * K + V * K * K) * norm;
                }
                break;
            case HIGHSHELF:
                if (peakGain >= 0) {    // boost
                    norm = 1 / (1 + Math.sqrt(2.0) * K + K * K);
                    a0 = (V + Math.sqrt(2.0*V) * K + K * K) * norm;
                    a1 = 2 * (K * K - V) * norm;
                    a2 = (V - Math.sqrt(2.0*V) * K + K * K) * norm;
                    b1 = 2 * (K * K - 1) * norm;
                    b2 = (1 - Math.sqrt(2.0) * K + K * K) * norm;
                }
                else {    // cut
                    norm = 1 / (V + Math.sqrt(2.0*V) * K + K * K);
                    a0 = (1 + Math.sqrt(2.0) * K + K * K) * norm;
                    a1 = 2 * (K * K - 1) * norm;
                    a2 = (1 - Math.sqrt(2.0) * K + K * K) * norm;
                    b1 = 2 * (K * K - V) * norm;
                    b2 = (V - Math.sqrt(2.0*V) * K + K * K) * norm;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know where is the problem...

I hope somebody can help me please!

Answer (score 0):

I did not really check the math calculations in behind (just don't know too much about this topic ). What I just recognized is that most calculations do not check for any overflow of the value.
That would somehow match your explaination that it works for 0dB setting and for lowering amplification.